# QGIS Data Plotly widgets not installing correctly

Tags: qgis, statistics, histogram, dataplotly

I'm using QGIS 3.28.6 Firenze and installed the most recent version of Data Plotly.  I'm trying to create a histogram with statistics of some data, and all the Data Plotly widgets don't show up when I open the plugin (images attached).  The documentation indicates there should be a statistics widget, but this doesn't install or show up for me.

How do I calculate statistics for a histogram of my data without this, or install Data Plotly correctly so that I can use the statistics widget/functions?

[image: What I see when I download Data Plotly][image: What the documentation shows for Data Plotly]

---

I still can't see statistics like the Data Plotly in this YouTube tutorial.

Do you know how I can add that feature to my version of Data Plotly?

I don't see this for the box plot type (like in the video) or histogram plot type.

[image]

Comment: I just installed it. The histogram button shows up if you are looking at the whole project. You are viewing the map layout.

Comment: It doesn't show up anywhere for me.